# How to increase gpuArray maximum variable size

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gpu

I'm trying to process a batch of images together, passing them to a GPU using `gpuArray`. 
`gpuDevice()` returns

```
TotalMemory: 6.4425e+09
AvailableMemory: 4.1330e+09
```

A size of the batch is 3.0845e+09, so I figure there is some kind of internal limitation to the gpuArray variable size.
Is there a way to overcome it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit on the size of a `gpuArray` - you cannot create a `gpuArray` where the number of elements exceeds `intmax('int32')`. When you attempt to exceed this upper bound, you should get a very specific error:

```
>> gpuArray.ones(1 + double(intmax('int32')), 1, 'uint8');
Error using gpuArray.ones
Maximum variable size allowed on the device is exceeded.
```

Comment: Thanks. So is there some kind of workaround? I'd like to use bigger variables

Comment: Your device only has 6GB of RAM - so overcoming the number of elements restriction is unlikely to get you much...